# I cannot change my pedals because of a plastic cap

Tags: pedals, replacement, pedals-flat

I cycle casually every day and I know at least something about bikes. But not that much that I know how to deal with the problem I experience.

Recently I got a new great bike (for me at least), but I noticed that the pedals were starting to get loose (issues with the thread). They are a basic plastic model, so I wanted to change them to something better.

Anyway, I got the new pedals and started working. I had an idea on how to do it, but after reading the instructions and an hour later I thought I was doing something wrong. So I watched a few videos on how to do it, and I was doing everything right.

Except this little problem...

The place where the Allen wrench should go, there is this plastic coin kinda thing, that very confidently says "*made in china*", that blocks the hole for the wrench (at least I suppose there is a hole for the wrench behind it). There is no point in telling about the bike because it was built in the local shop and the pedals don't have a brand and it won't help if I tell you the other parts.

So my question is, how do I change my pedals?

Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: Curious why the downvote?

Comment: I am also curious. I thought there was already a made post about something similar somewhere, but now that a user like you mentioned it, I feel a big relief. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that a user like me is much of a vote of confidence ;-).  The question seems relevant, it deals with a useful mechanical topic and shows research prior to asking the question.  And, unrelated, welcome!  This is a pretty friendly group.

Comment: I did not downvote but one imagines that many people read the repeated emphasis on the place of origin being the root of the problem as being highly politically-charged content that is off-topic to the bicycle maintenance question.

Comment: A photo of the detail that stands in the way would help immensely to help you.

Comment: I might add to what Affe said, that without an illustration / photo it sounds like you may be referring to the dust cap on the outside that covers the bolt for adjusting bearings on some pedals. Having nothing to do with the threads to the crank.
Cheap pedals of any origin are indeed less likely to have a hex point on the inboard side of the crank, but I've never seen one with a cap on the inside, just on the outside of the pedal. From your question, it is unclear what you were even trying to wrench on.

Comment: Fair enough. I will know better next time. You have my apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all pedals have hex-socket insets on them.  This is especially true for cheap pedals that come on some bikes.

You should invest in a proper pedal tool, which is a 15 mm wrench with a narrow profile, widely available from tool manufacturers. If you look closely at the area between the pedal itself and the crank you will see two small "flats" or "lands".  This is where the pedal tool fits and you can then tighten or loosen it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw it on one of the videos, but for some reason I insisted on using the allen wrench. This makes life way easier.

Comment: This link is only visible within the US. I got a big pop-up banner blaming GDPR as why I couldn't see the content of the link.

Comment: Well you have only your own government to blame for GDPR.  Anyway, search for Park PW-3 and I'm sure there is a dealer near you.

Comment: I've dealt with 100s of bikes, and never come across one that didn't have flats for a standard open-end pedal wrench.  Some do have allen recesses in the end of the shaft, but this is mainly to speed factory assembly.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Lightweight aftermarket pedals can have thin spindles without 15mm flats. But sure, cheap OEM pedals always have them.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I have three pairs of Crankbrothers clipless pedals, ranging from cheapest to more expensive, and none of them have flats. Of these, two pairs have 6 mm hex holes, and one has 8 mm holes. Other 3-4 pairs of flat pedals that I have lying around do have flats, some of them additionally have 6 mm hex recesses.

Comment: jwh20, if someone makes a suggestion for an edit, there may be other readers having the same experience as @Luuklag so why not try and include them? If a post can work without a link then all the better and product recs aren't needed anyway as they can go obsolete and now the answer will be longer lasting.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Look pedals don't have flats.

Comment: Or, alternatively, do not link an US-only eshop but link the official manufacturer's page.